# com.comscore.analytics.Census.getInstance().notifyStart();

Tags: android

I am working as an Android trainee, I was referring some application code, I saw the following lines in the app code.

```
// Analytics code
    com.comscore.analytics.Census.getInstance().notifyStart(
        getApplicationContext(),
        "6035310",
        "bc394b19c1cdf3087f51d9365147c214");
}
```

Can anyone tell me, what does it stands for. I had searched for that but couldn't find its use and necessity. Any help or tip will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should remove the two string values from the question, replace them with ### or similar.

Answer (score 0):

The code is initiating the Comscore tracking SDK (http://www.comscore.com/). It is notifying the library that the application has started. Comscore is one of the popular state-tracking libraries available to companies developing cross-platform apps.

In particular: The code is making a static call to the Census class (com.comscore.analytics.Census); to get a static instance (getInstance() - one assumes it's created the first time this is called); and on that instance it is calling the method notifyStart().

The arguments, in order, are:

- A Context for the app (any Context should do -
  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html)
- The publisher's c2 value (roughly comparable with their
  API Key)
- The publisher's secret

Answer (score 0):

This code refers to the event tracking of the Application in the market.
It is using famous comScore Application Tag library.
It follows the following code syntax:

// Initialize comScore Application Tag library
comScore.setAppContext(this.getApplicationContext());

Parameter 1--->clientID
Parameter 2--->PublisherSecret

the above code should be inside onCreate()

Hope this would helps you to understand about code you asked.